# Two questions about convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having some issues with two problems and I would really appreciate some general guidance on how to go about proving them.

1) Prove or disprove: Assume |x$_{n}$| $\rightarrow$ L. Then (x$_{n}$) has a convergent subsequence.

2) Let r denote a rational number. Define x$_{n}$ = sin(n!r$\pi$). Show lim$_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ x$_{n}$ exists.

For 1, I think I've made a mistake. So far, I have:

If x$_{n}$ $\geq$ 0, then |x$_{n}$| = x$_{n}$ $\rightarrow$ L, and so x$_{n}$ is a convergent subsequence of itself. Similarly, if x$_{n}$ $\lt$ 0, we get |x$_{n}$| = -x$_{n}$ $\rightarrow$ -L, so again x$_{n}$ is a subsequence of itself. If x$_{n}$ oscillates, then.... I'm kind of unsure what to do next. I feel like I need to show x$_{n}$ is bounded and then use the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem but I'm unsure of how to do so.

For 2, I really have no idea how to approach this. Should I approach this using subsequences, and then look into the limit points? I'm not sure why the limit actually exists. Shouldn't it still oscillate between -1 and 1? I don't want an answer, but I would really appreciate someone giving me a good first step in the right direction.

Comment: Won't $|x_n|<L+1$ hold eventually?

Answer (score 0):

For $1)$, note that $|x_n| \to L \implies$ $\exists$ $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $||x_n| - L| < 1$ for all $n \ge n_0$. But $|x_n| - L \le ||x_n| - L| < 1 \implies |x_n| < L + 1$ for all $n \ge n_0$. Therefore $|x_n| \le \max(|x_1|,...,|x_{n_0}|, L+1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. By BW, it follows that $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

For $2)$, put $r = a/b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb Z$. We have that $b | n!$ for all $n \ge |b|$. Therefore $\sin(n! r \pi)$ is identically zero eventually.